# Funky Image Positioning in react native?

Tags: css, image, react-native

I'm trying to create an image that fits snugly at the top of the screen of my device. Basically, a header image. At long last I've been able to scale the image to the width of the screen, but now that I have it, it always gives itself an extra top margin that I can't seem to get around. I've played around with flex properties but nothing seems to work! I was wondering if anyone had experienced an issue like this before. I'm a bit new to CSS and such so forgive me if my question is dumb.

Here is what appears (the margin is well above 25 pixels): 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6KYq.jpg

My code is as follows (simplified for you all):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native'; 

export class Home extends Component {
  static NavOption = {
    title: 'Home',
  };
  render() { 
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-start'}}>
          <Image 
              source={require('./pictures/my-image.png')}
              style={styles.headerImage}
              resizeMode='contain'
            />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  headerImage: { 
    maxWidth: '100%',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gordon, not a dumb question. I am having the exact same issue. I did what ReyHaynes suggested (thanks!) but in my case, modified the example he linked to for my situation:

[original example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36028906/image-alignment-when-using-resizemode-contain/36077412#36077412)

The example expects a static maxWidth/maxHeight to return a set of dimensions for your image. Since i didn't know what those vars needed to be, here's how i modified his example to work for my situation:

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
```

then, change this...

```
var maxWidth = 110;
var maxHeight = 30;
```

to...

```
  var maxWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
  var maxHeight = height;
```

Finally, follow the original example and implement as he suggested.

Answer (score 1):

`resizeMode='contain'` actually centers and pads the image based on how it's resized. You will have to calculate and set the height dynamically.

Here is a good example of how that can be done:
[Image Alignment when using resizeMode = contain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36077412/3460600)